# PHP 8.1, Wordpress - Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Unknown format specifier "M" in /var/www/vhosts/

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, php-8, wordpress-6

Please help...........
The PHP code is here:

```
$image_output = sprintf(
        '<img title="'.$title.'" src="%1$s" alt="%2$s"%3$s %4$s />%5$s',
        $thumb_src ? esc_attr( $thumb_src ) : '',
        $title ? esc_attr( $title ) : '',
        ( !empty( $args['img_class'] ) ? sprintf( ' class="%s"', esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['img_class'] ) ) ) : '' ),
        ( !empty( $img_style ) ? sprintf( ' style="%s"', esc_attr( $img_style ) ) : '' ),
        $args['img_after'] ? $args['img_after'] : ''
    );
```

Comment: `$s` contains 'M'. That's creates an invalid format string for printf.